# Spark TSV file and incorrect column spit

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have TSV file with many of lines. Much of the lines work fine but I have the issue of working with the following line:

```
tt7841930   tvEpisode   "Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded "Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded 0   2018    \N  24  Animation,Family
```

I use Spark and Scala in order to load the file into DataFrame:

```
val titleBasicsDf = spark.read
  .format("org.apache.spark.csv")
  .option("header", true)
  .option("inferSchema", true)
  .option("delimiter", "    ")
  .csv("title.basics.tsv.gz")
```

As result I receive:

```
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------+----------------+------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+-------------+
|tconst   |titleType|primaryTitle                                                                   |originalTitle|isAdult|startYear|endYear|runtimeMinutes  |genres|averageRating|numVotes|parentTconst|seasonNumber|episodeNumber|
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------+----------------+------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+-------------+
|tt7841930|tvEpisode|"Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded    "Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded|0            |2018   |\N       |24     |Animation,Family|null  |null         |null    |tt4947580   |6           |2            |
+---------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------+---------+-------+----------------+------+-------------+--------+------------+------------+-------------+
```

So as you may see, the following data in the line:

```
"Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded "Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded
```

is not properly split into two different values for `primaryTitle` and `originalTitle` columns and `primaryTitle` contains both of them:

```
{
   "runtimeMinutes":"Animation,Family",
   "tconst":"tt7841930",
   "seasonNumber":"6",
   "titleType":"tvEpisode",
   "averageRating":null,
   "originalTitle":"0",
   "parentTconst":"tt4947580",
   "startYear":null,
   "endYear":"24",
   "numVotes":null,
   "episodeNumber":"2",
   "primaryTitle":"\"Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded\t\"Stop and Hear the Cicadas/Cold-Blooded",
   "isAdult":2018,
   "genres":null
}
```

What am I doing wrong and how to configure Spark to properly understand and split this line? As I mentioned previously, many of other lines from this file are split correctly into the proper columns.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here: https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv/issues/89

> The way to turn off the default escaping of the double quote character
>   (") with the backslash character () - i.e. to avoid escaping for all
>   characters entirely, you must add an .option() method call with just
>   the right parameters after the .write() method call. The goal of the
>   option() method call is to change how the csv() method "finds"
>   instances of the "quote" character as it is emitting the content. To
>   do this, you must change the default of what a "quote" actually means;
>   i.e. change the character sought from being a double quote character
>   (") to a Unicode "\u0000" character (essentially providing the Unicode
>   NUL character assuming it won't ever occur within the document).

the following magic option did the trick:

```
.option("quote", "\u0000")
```